# Can someone help me find the solution to this differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this differential equation

$$ \dfrac{\text{d}^2y}{dx^2}- \dfrac{y_0-y}{a}   \dfrac{\text{d}y}{dx}-\dfrac{y}{b}\sqrt{1+\left(b\dfrac{\text{d}y}{dx}\right)^2} =0$$
where $ y_0 $ , $a $ and $b$ are constants.

This is the equation for current (y) in a catalyst layer (along the length x) in a PEM fuel cell. I have the graph for the analytical solution from a book but I am trying to obtain the exact expression. Unfortunately, I am not able to download the research paper where the analytical solution is described and therefore looking for some help.

I am not sure how to solve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide [additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and the community. Some forms of context include background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.